# Py3k libraries porting

Tags: python, porting

I don't really know if this is a StackOverflow-type question or a Python-dev question. I'd like to host sprints at my place for converting python2.0 libraries to Python3 ; currently I am working on porting Distutils2.

1. Is there any place I could find a
   graph/log of the
   libraries(dependencies) which need
   to be ported to Python3 ranked by
   importance?(By importance, I mean
   that a distribution being used as a
   dependency for a lot of other
   distributions.)
2. Also, If you have a particular
   distribution that you are
   maintaining and would like to have
   some help porting it to Python3,
   please do feel free to mention it
   below.

Comment: Although I'm not sure it belongs to SO, this is a wonderful question, at least in its intentions. The best place to ask it is the official Python mailing lists `python-dev` and `python-list`. Personally, this question interests me as well and I would like to help in the porting effort. I think that if you can built a thrust behind this initiative you can end up doing a huge service to the Python language and community

Comment: Good advice.  Also, a bit of a nit: it would be better to use ther term `Python 3` rather than `Python 3.0` to avoid confusion between the Python 3 language in general and the specific 3.0 initial release of it which, as you probably know, was officially and quickly retired with the release of Python 3.1.

Comment: @Eli, thanks i'll post a query to the mailing list asap.
@Ned, thanks i've made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [list of packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all) available for Python 3.0 at PyPI.  You can also view a complete list at the same site, and perhaps try to determine which packages haven't been ported yet.

You may also be interested in [PSF sponsored sprints](http://lwn.net/Articles/395641/) announced recently and consider applying for funding or publicity:

> The PSF is happy to open our first call for applications for sprint funding!
>
> [...]
>
> The Python Software Foundation has set aside funds to be distributed to
> world-wide sprint efforts. We're anticipating 2-3 events per month focused on
> covering topics to help the entire community

Answer (score 0):

There is a  *"I wish there was Python 3 support in"* poll on the Python website, you can take a look at the [results](http://python.org/3kpoll).